# Enter docker container from host using docker-machine

Tags: php, docker, containers, phpstorm

How can I connect to Php container from my Windows machine?

I run docker toolbox https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox on my Windows 10 machine. It's create docker-machine (env default) using virtualbox on port tcp://192.168.99.100:2376 and from host machine (Windows) I can connect to it by ssh. Inside docker-machine I run containers with docker-compose.

I run PhpStorm on Windows and I want to configure PHP interpreter to listen to containerized php. I have read https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+Remote+PHP+Interpreters+in+PhpStorm but still no sure how to configure it.

Comment: Remote PHP Interpreters in PhpStorm use SSH to execute/debug your remote code. As far as I'm aware this is not a solution when using docker as it does not use (and strongly not recommends) SSH inside actual containers.

Comment: So, how can I configure my PhpStorm terminal to run php, unittest, drush without ssh into my machine and from there into docker. How make it native - load Phpterminal - run php, composer, drush. What script or something else

Answer (score 0):

I found http://obrown.io/2015/12/23/phpunit-docker-phpstorm.html

The goal create local php script and somehow provide in it connection to php.
In the example author create new container and execute/link php there

## End of "docker-machine env default" output

/usr/local/bin/docker run -i --rm -v "${PWD}":"${PWD}" -w ${PWD} --net=host --sig-proxy=true --pid=host originalbrownbear/php:7-cli-phpunit php "$@"

How can I configure such script to use existing docker container with php?

Nornally I enter running container - docker exec -it container_tag_name /bin/bash
And there I can execute php.